# Select com paletas de cores

Tags: html, css

Como consigo fazer um select com paletas de cores dentro, preciso fazer a seleção de determinadas cores, porém não por nome e sim por paletas que identificarão cada cor, veja um exemplo

[image: repare que tem select normais de texto e um select de cores]

Alguém conhece como, um tutorial ou por onde começar?

Valeu!

Comment: Cara.. Tem uma biblioteca chamada "Jscolor"... Vou deixar a referência aqui... Dai você pode fazer isso direto de uma textbox, é bem fácil: http://jscolor.com/examples/

Comment: opa obrigado, ainda sim não me serve, quero algo mas simples e penso que seja possivel apenas com css sem uso de biblioteca ou javascript, no meu caso preciso definir apenas umas 5 cores no maximo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desenvolvi uma "solução" caseira claro que precisa melhorar mas vê se ajuda.

```js
var cores = document.querySelectorAll("label[for^='cor']");

for(i = 0; i < cores.length; i++)
{
  cores[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("input[name='seleciona-cor']").checked = false;
  });
}
```

```css
.cores{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.cores input[name="seleciona-cor"]{
  display: none;
}

.cores label[for="seleciona-cor"]{
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.cores label[for="seleciona-cor"]::after{
  display: block;
  content: "\1a06";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: relative;
}

.cores label[for="seleciona-cor"]:checked::after{
  content: "\1a08";
}

.cores input[name="seleciona-cor"]:checked ~ .cor label{
  display: block;
}

input[name="cor"]{
  display: none;
}

input[name="cor"]:checked + label::after{
  content: "\2713";
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

input[name="cor"]:checked + label{
  display: block;
}

label[for^="cor"]{
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cores">
  
  <label for="seleciona-cor"></label>
  <input id="seleciona-cor" type="checkbox" name="seleciona-cor" />

  <div class="cor">    
    <input id="cor1" type="radio" name="cor" value="blue" checked />
    <label for="cor1" style="background-color: blue"></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cor">
    <input id="cor2" type="radio" name="cor" value="red" />
    <label for="cor2" style="background-color: red"></label>    
  </div>
  
  <div class="cor">
    <input id="cor3" type="radio" name="cor" value="green" />
    <label for="cor3" style="background-color: green"></label>    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Carai mano, bem bolado kkkkk, gostei, deu até pra min ter outras idéias em cima da sua, consegui ter uma básica da logica de por onde começar, legal, gostei, muito obrigado pela ajuda, vai me ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer desta forma, mas é impossível você retirar a opção de outro.

```html
<input type="color" id="cores" name="ArcoIris" list="arcoIris" value="#FF0000">
<datalist id="arcoIris">
<option value="#FF0000">Vermelho</option>
<option value="#FFA500">Laranja</option>
<option value="#FFFF00">Amarelo</option>
<option value="#008000">Verde</option>
<option value="#0000FF">Azul</option>
<option value="#4B0082">Indigo</option>
<option value="#EE82EE">Violeta</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: caramba, era bem isso que estava precisando, pena que a opção "outro" não pode ser tirada >(

Comment: @Patrique Infelizmente ela é posta ali pelo próprio Navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Bem eu pensei em duas possibilidades: 
1 - Você usa imagens no select com as cores que você quer (ou `background-color`):

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(vermelho.png);">vermelho</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(amarelo.png);">amarelo</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(azul.png);">azul</option>
</select>
```

2 - Use o elemento input type color

```
 <!--elemento html5 color, verifique quais navegadores compativeis-->
  <form> 
   <input type="color" name="favcolor">
 </form>
```

O input type color vai abrir uma paleta para selecionar a cor desejada

Tutorial de Referência: 
http://www.escolaw3.com/tutoriais/html/input-types#color

Comment: O primeiro caso não funcionou, no segundo aparecem todas as cores possíveis, pra mim não da pois eu quero limitar as cores, de qualquer forma agradeço a atenção e fico ainda pela espera de alguma sugestão para o meu caso, obrigado.

Comment: Entendo. pesquisei o segundo caso e não encontrei uma maneira de limitar as cores. 

Mas no primeiro caso, o que deu errado? simplesmente não funcionou? ou não funcionou da maneira que você precisava?
eu testei aqui e a cor apareceu na lista...

Comment: Oi paulo, será uma opção para escolha do layout, porém vou limitar a 5 cores, por isso preciso especificar apenas 5 cores e não da a opção para outras;